# Strange XML problem works in 2.2 not in 2.1

Tags: android, xml

I have this problem which i have narrowed down to the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
```

in the code:

```
   public class Tabs extends Activity {
        Activity currentActivity;
        TabHost tabHost;
        TabWidget tabWidget;
        BrRefreshBarView refreshBar;
        BrRSSView newsView;
        BrRSSView blogView;
        BrSplashLayout splashLayout;
        BrImageView splashImage;
        BrProgressBar loadingBar;
        BrRSS newsrss;
        LinearLayout toolbar;
        BrRSS blogrss;
        LoadRSSTask _initTask; 
        @Override   
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            BrScreenMetrics.setMetrics(this);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    //      currentActivity = this;
    //           
    //      tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); 
    //      tabWidget = (TabWidget)findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    //      
    //      tabHost.setup();
    //      tabHost.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

this is my tabs.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="65dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_weight="0" android:gravity="bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically in 2.1 it just crashes immediately with that TabHost block in the xml, nothing in logcat. However in 2.2 it works perfectly.

Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="se.brickit.farsta"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />     
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />     

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icons_appicon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Tabs" android:label="Tabs">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.TABS"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity android:name="se.brickit.internal.BrRSSDetailActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I made a almost a replica from google tutorial but more detail and it works for me. [link](http://subspider-mobile.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work well in the 2.1 not in the 2.2.I have the similar problem several days ago.In the 2.2,I think,you should change `setContentView(R.layout.tabs)` to `InflatorLayout.from(this).....` you can refer to some documents.

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to achieve the Tab Layout is shown well, maybe you should extend your Activity into TabActivity. and then, set **tabHost = getTabHost();**